# not able to send data through postman for register api

Tags: javascript, express, postman

i am trying to send data thorough post for register api. but data is not getting send. i am not getting what is the exact issue. i also tried to change settings of postman but it did not worked. i also tinkered with validation rules but also did not worked.

here is my register api code

```
app.use(express.json()); // middleware

 app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const newUser = await User.create(req.body);
      res.status(200).json(newUser); // Send the newly created user as a response
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  });
```

my user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const validateEmail = function (email) {
  const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  return emailRegex.test(email);
};

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Your Name"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Your Email"],
    validate: {
      validator: validateEmail,
      message: "Please fill a valid email address",
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Your Password"],
  },
});

UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    this.password = hashedPassword;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;|
```

Header

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 5da77db1-867b-4919-a02d-c343704b6eb2
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 99
Request Body
{
    "name":"pratik",
    "email":"zajampratik@gmail.com",
    "password":"PratikZajam@1999"
}
Response Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 136
ETag: W/"88-VEpd9WSTE7wFAEzw7xIMM06sJpo"
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2023 09:55:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Postman request

```
{
    "name":"pratik",
    "email":"zajampratik@gmail.com",
    "password":"PratikZajam@1999"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "message": "User validation failed: password: Please Enter Your Password, email: Please Enter Your Email, name: Please Enter Your Name"
}
```

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FoGD.png)

i have tried almost everything but it did not worked. i am preety new to javascript

Comment: You question lacks (a) Your body parsing middleware configuration (b) Any logging of what the value of req.body actually is (c) A **text** representation of your request (d) Details of the request headers you are sending from postman (I generally recommend using [.http files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which are (a) text so each to copy/paste/share (b) supported by a variety of REST testing clients

Comment: The URL is not [the headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Comment: i have added middleware info as well as header info in the code

Answer (score -1):

if you are using express,

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Or use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: i am allready using this middleware

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: Seems like the error is coming from User.create...
try something like this
const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
await small.save();